# How many active UIWebViews iPhone/iPod app can handle at one time?

Tags: iphone, ipad

How many UIWebViews iPhone/iPod applications can have at one time (i.e. all loaded into memory and active)? For example iPhone's Safari can have max. 8 UIWebView tabs (for iPad, it's 9 tabs).

I'm planning to have the UIWebViews presented as pages using UIPageControl (portrait mode only app; UIWebViews will use `loadHTMLString:baseURL:` to load local resources, some references to images from the web).

According to docs "there is a limit of about 20 page indicators on the screen before they are clipped."
I don't plan to go that wild, but how many active UIWebViews can any iPhone/iPod application have?

BTW: I'm aware that having that many web views as pages is a very resource demanding approach.